# echoing html in a bash string

Tags: html, string, bash

I am complete bash newbie.

I want to use the bash `>>`operator to append some html to the end of a file. I would like to construct said HTML with three concatenated sections: an opening html tag, a variable defined by bash earlier, and a closing html tag.

Something like:

```
echo <div id="myid"> $myBashVariable </div> >> file.html
```

I am not sure what syntax is needed to escape the various characters needed for the HTML markup... `<`,`>`,`/`,`"`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\ is the escape character that you have to add before the special characters to escape the special meaning of those.

Try this.

```
echo \<div id=\"myid\"\> $myBashVariable \</div\> >> file.html
```

Answer (score 4):

Save yourself the trouble and use a here document:

```
#!/bin/sh
var="world"

cat >> file.html << EOF
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello $var</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="whatever">Hello $var, and welcome to my page.</div>
  </body>
</html>
EOF
```

Note that characters in `$var` will not be HTML escaped, so if `var='<script>alert(1)</script>'` you will get a JS popup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape with `\`

On windows,

```
echo "<div id=\"myid\">%myBashVariable%</div>" >> file.html
```

On Linux,

```
echo \<div\ id=\"myid\"\>$myBashVariable\</div\> >> file.html
```